API endpoint in Postman or Laravel route gives "Login timeout expired" but DB accessible with Tinker

Laravel 10 Sail in Docker container under php8.1 on localhost:8000 with ODBC Driver 18 and pdo_sqlsrv & sqlsrv extensions enabled. WSL2
Remote SQL Server Database on SQL Server 2016 using SQL Authentication and self-signed certificate.

Trying to setup with a Remote SQL Server DB, I am able to connect to the DB via Tinker, which suggests my .env and database.php file are correct however I am getting SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired error when trying to access API endpoints.
Files
.env
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=185.181.160.119
DB_PORT=21433
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=pass

cors.php
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

database.php
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'dbo',
            'encrypt' => env('DB_ENCRYPT', 'yes'),
            'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'true'),
            'options' => [
                // PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT => 60,
                PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8
            ],
        ],

What could I be missing?

You have two ports in your config, so that's aready wrong, please read the documentation instead of trying to guess things

Which documentation? I am new to working with SQL Server DB. Normally ports are displayed after semicolon, not comma so it occured as a specificity.

I made a test API Route:
Route::get('/test-db-connection', function () {
        try {
            // Output current database configuration
            $dbConfig = Config::get('database.connections.' . Config::get('database.default'));
            unset($dbConfig['password']); // Don't expose the password

            $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Database connection successful',
                'driver' => DB::connection()->getDriverName(),
                'database' => DB::connection()->getDatabaseName(),
                'config' => $dbConfig
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Database connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Database connection failed',
                'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                'file' => $e->getFile(),
                'line' => $e->getLine(),
                'config' => $dbConfig ?? null,
                'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString()
            ], 500);
        }
    });

to check the connection and Laravel was using the mysql connection as returned in config even though I had set:
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv')in /config/database.php. (Was taken in consideration at runtime hence Tinker could access it, though I do not know why).
Adding DB_CONNECTION env var in docker-compose.yml:
environment:
    DB_CONNECTION: sqlsrv

and rebuilding the sail container with:
sail down
sail build --no-cache
sail up -d

Solved the issue.
